# Error when uploading jpeg by POST WP8 C#

Tags: post, jpeg, converters

I have a problem when I POST a JPEG file with WebClient. 
I have converted my "image.jpg" to byte [], I send it to the Web Service but the image is corrupted.
There is a specific way to convert a JPEG file to byte []?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no specific way. Files are just files to the system it does not care if it is a image, video or a dll.

To read a file into a byte stream you can use:

```
File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
```

I personally would use EasyHTTP (https://github.com/hhariri/EasyHttp) to post the file stream:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.Post(URL, ByteStream, ContentType);
```

Comment: So my problem don't come from the conversion

Comment: Well that is hard to tell. I assume not, are you sending the correct content type?